# PHP implode array to create query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, implode

The idea is to create the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1
UNION SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2
UNION SELECT column1, column2 FROM table3
ORDER BY 'column3'";
```

I wanna keep it DRY tho, so I came up with the following already thinking about the possible dozens of tables I might use:

```
$tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
$array_of_tables = array('SELECT column1, column2 FROM ', $tables[0]);

for($i = 1; $i < count($tables); $i++){
    array_push($array_of_tables, "UNION SELECT column1, column2 FROM " . $tables[$i]);
}

array_push($array_of_tables, "ORDER BY 'eng'" . '"');

$sql = implode('', $array_of_tables);
```

I get the correct string, however I'm not able to use it. Could anyone please tell me what's going on and how to fix it - please, explain in newbie terms! I'm new to PHP and decided to give it a shot, even though half the internet says it's not worthy it. Cheers!

Comment: Please include what the actual issue you encountered when running your attempt is, including a traceback.

Comment: You shouldn't have single quotes around the column name in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I wondered if there are missing spaces around the various sections of the query. Maybe imploding with a space might make a difference. I'd expect that to be clear in the query string though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, there just some problems with the details:

1. You have no whitespace between the pieces that you're imploding, so it's ending up like `... FROM table1UNION SELECT ...`. Use `implode(' ', $array_of_tables)`.
2. You have quotes around the column in the `ORDER BY` clause. That will order by a literal string, not the column values. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks).

If you need to combine these tables frequently, you might want to look into using MySQL's [MERGE Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/merge-storage-engine.html). This allows you to create a virtual table whose contents are the combination of several other tables.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's now fixed. Thanks for the links too. I'll read them. Cheeers!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<?php
$tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
$array_of_tables = array('SELECT column1, column2 FROM ', $tables[0]);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($tables); $i++) {
    array_push($array_of_tables, " UNION SELECT column1, column2 FROM " . $tables[$i]);
}

array_push($array_of_tables, " ORDER BY 'eng'");

$sql = implode('', $array_of_tables);
```

Comment: thanks, BBoriko! I imploded the array with and space and unquoted 'eng' and it worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the intent of the for loop. I would solve it like this:

```
$tables = array('table1', 'table2', 'table3');
$sel = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM ";
$sql = $sel . implode(" UNION $sel",$tables) . " ORDER BY 'eng'";
```

Comment: thank you for your response! How would I do if I keep adding tables and want them to be displayed? Should I keep adding the tables to $tables or is there a way of doing it like using ...args in JS?

Comment: yes, just add them to `$tables`. the `implode()` joins all the parts together with the apropriate in-fill